# Найти архивы по последней дате на SFTP сервере

Tags: python, sftp

Я подключился к SFTP серверу с помощью библиотеки paramiko, прописал путь к нужной мне папке, но в ней лежит несколько архивов. Мне нужно найти архивы созданые последней датой ( в данном случае это два файла 01.11.2021) Я не нашёл способа сделать это внутри SFTP сервера. Скрин прилагаю ниже

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='hostname',username='username',password='password!')
ftp_client= ssh_client.open_sftp()

    with ftp_client.open(".../nop/GSM","r", bufsize=32768) as f:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Насколько я помню, формат отдачи содержимого каталога FTP серверов не очень стандартизован. Поэтому либо пробовать библиотеки какие-то для ftp, смогут ли они выдачу конкретного сервера нормально распарсить, либо самому парсить содержимое каталога. Если я правильно всё понял, конечно.

Comment: Так всё-таки FTP или SFTP? Что такое `ftp_client`?

Comment: Посмотрел доку на `paramiko`, там же есть функция `listdir_attr`, она вроде содержит какие-то временные метки в себе, можно через неё посмотреть попробовать дату и время создания/изменения

Comment: @andreymal Отредактировал вопрос, добавил переменную ftp_client

Comment: @CrazyElf функция listdir_attr у меня работает только на корень sftp - ftp_client.listdir_attr(). А на полный путь к моей папке f.listdir_attr() не работает, выдает ошибку 'SFTPFile' object has no attribute 'listdir_attr'

Comment: @CrazyElf Если использовать функцию вот так - ftp_client.listdir_attr((f)) . Выдаёт Error  Expected unicode or bytes, got <paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile object at 0x000001D5E0EE6B50>